# Can an Apple Track Pad and Magic Mouse be used at the same time?

Tags: trackpad, mouse

I have a New 2011 iMac which came with the magic Mouse, I would like the option of having a trackpad as well for multi-touch gestures and scrolling up and down etc, but would also like the mouse for times when moving windows around and for programmes like Final Cut and Photoshop where for me a mouse is easier to use.

Will they work together well with out interfering? obviously I will not be scrolling with one and moving with the other, I just want to switch between the two as and when I want.

I would only like answers from personally experienced sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works fine. I have both on my 2010 iMac, and as long as you don't try to use them simultaneously, there are no problems.